How do I draw a golden patina texture on wood?

I have such a sample and I need to repeat this golden patina, here on this model, however, there is only one brush in the blender to draw on the texture and it is just round. I realized that I needed to mix two materials and draw using the alpha channel, but I didn't know how to do it correctly.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Do you have a height / bump map in your wood material? you could use that as a mask for painting..
